# SASS functions used to create whole properties inside a selector

Tags: function, sass, media-queries

My goal is to decrease repetitiveness in my scss file, by not having to write out "@media..." a ton of times.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
@function atMediaAll($property, $xsValue, $sValue, $mValue) {
  @return "@media screen and (min-width:" + $break-xs + "){" + $property + ":" + $xsValue + ";}";
  @return "@media screen and (min-width:" + $break-s + "){" + $property + ":" + $sValue + ";}";
  @return "@media screen and (min-width:" + $break-m + "){" + $property + ":" + $mValue + ";}";
}
```

Then call it inside of a selector with something like this:

```
@include atMediaAll("background-position", "-25px 0", "-35px 0", "-45px 0");
```

Is there an equivalent to the "@include" for function, or some other way to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have employed this method:

```
@mixin atMedia($screenSize) {
  @if $screenSize == xs{
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px ){@content;}
  }
  @else if $screenSize == s{
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px ){@content;}
  }
  @else if $screenSize == m{
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px ){@content;}
  }
}

@include atMedia(xs) {background-position: -25px 0;}
@include atMedia(s) {background-position: -35px 0;}
@include atMedia(m) {background-position: -45px 0;}
```

It takes of less space, but it is still very repetitive.